# kNN which is correct Euclidean distance vs linalg.norm?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python

I'm programing a k-Nearest Neighbour classification function in python. To calculate the distance I did two different implementations and I'm wondering what the difference is and why. Also, which one is more correct.

Method one:

```
def EuclideanDistance1(vector1, vector2):
   dist = 0.0
   for i in range(len(vector1)-1):
      dist += (vector1[i] - vector2[i])**2
   return sqrt(dist)

dataset = [[2.7810836,2.550537003,0], [1.465489372,2.362125076,0], [3.396561688,4.400293529,0],
       [1.38807019,1.850220317,0], [3.06407232,3.005305973,0], [7.627531214,2.759262235,1],
       [5.332441248,2.088626775,1], [6.922596716,1.77106367,1], [8.675418651,-0.242068655,1],
       [7.673756466,3.508563011,1]]

row0 = dataset[0]
for row in dataset:
    distance = EuclideanDistance1(row0, row)
    print(distance)
```

Method two:

```
def EuclideanDistance(vector1, vector2):
    # intializing 
    point1 = np.array(vector1) 
   point2 = np.array(vector2) 
    # calculating Euclidean distance to do so using np.linalg.norm function. To 
    # https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-nplinalgnorm-method-in-numpy
    # https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html#:~:text=The%20Frobenius%20norm%2C%20sometimes%20also,considered%20as%20a%20vector%20norm.
    dist = np.linalg.norm(point1 - point2) 
    return dist

#printing Euclidean distance 
row0 = dataset[0]
for row in dataset:
    distance = EuclideanDistance(row0, row)
    print(distance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct as they calculate the same thing but the numpy one should be much faster (you may want to time them to see this). In general your own implementation is very clumsy as it uses a for loop which is unnecessary. If you want to create your own implementation (though it still likely wont be as fast as numpy's one) then vectorize it and do something like:

```
def EuclideanDistance1(vector1, vector2):
   dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((vector1 - vector2)**2))
   return dist
```

but I would just use:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html